Include related tags when filtering by a specific tag
I have a Power BI report where I'm using a table named Words that contains two columns, index-id (numeric) and tag (text). Some tags are related to others, such as "Channel" and "Special+".
1. Words table
     ||Index-tag || Tag ||
             168 | Palestine
            1000 | Special +
            1159 | Channel
             192 | News
             340 | Search

When I filter the report by selecting "Special +" from the tag column, I want it to not only show the rows with "Special +" but also include the related "Channel" rows.
To achieve this, I created a table named tag_grouping with two columns, index-id and id. In the tag_grouping table, the first row has index-id corresponding to the index-id from the Words table for the tag "Channel" and id corresponding to the index-id from the Words table for the tag "Special +". The second row has both columns containing the index-id for the tag "Special +".
 2 . Tag_grouping table
      ||Index-id || id ||
      1159 | 1000
      1000 |1000

Here's the model :
Model_hierarchy
However, still when I filter the report by selecting "Special +" from the tag column, it only shows the rows with "Special +" and does not include the related "Channel" rows.
Example
How can I modify my Power BI report report or relationships to use the second inactive one and include the related tags when filtering by a specific tag?
